# How to generate a line of images programmatically on Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to make an iOS game and it requires for the players to catch as many coins as it can. I know to show the coins programmatically, but how do I make a line of coins with ease. Similarly like the game line runner where the runner has to catch the coins or jetpack joyride?

I'm thinking of something like 
The game is landscape

```
randomPlace = arc3random()%315;
coinImage.center = CGPointMake(coinImage.center.x - 1, randomPlace);
coinImage1.center = CGPointMake(coinImage1.center.x - 1, randomPlace);
```

I don't even know if I'm on the right track but can anyone help me? thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this to create 5 images in a horizontal line:

```
    //Generate your variables
    float width = 15, height = 15;
    float originX = 20, originY = 50, spacing = 5;

    //Create 5 image views
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

        UIImageView *imgV = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(originX + ((spacing + width) * i), originY, width, height)];
        [imgV setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YourImage.png"]];
        [self.view addSubview:imgV];
    }
```

Which will produce something like this:

[image: 5 images in a line!]

Comment: is there a way I can do this with UIImageView?

Comment: This answer is using `UIImageView`s, what's your question?